# transmitting Smart card data from GPIO

Tags: microcontroller, smartcard

I am trying to access the Smart card from the C8051 micro-controller. I am able to receive the ATR from the smart card after reset . when i try to send  commands from the same GPIO line, there is no response from the smart card.

in this program i am using interrupt based technique where whenever the signal at GPIO goes low interrupt is triggered as a result we start receiving the data. but when i send the command this interrupt is not trigrred.

```
void transmit_smart_data(void)
{
    char j=0,parity,k=0,y=0,q=0;
    puts("smart\n\r");
    IE_EX0=0;   //disabling interrupt
    P0MDIN |=P0_B7;
    P0MDOUT|=P0_B7;
    while(valid_tx=getchar(),valid_tx!='b')                 //last character of the command is 'a'(asumption)
    {
        valid_data[j]=valid_tx;
    }
    valid_data[j]='z';
    puts("valid\n\r");
       j=0;
        while(valid_data[j]!='z')
        {
           parity=parity_data(valid_data[j]);
           putchar(parity);
             P0_B7=0;
             TMR2RL  = -4550;                  // Init reload values
             TMR2    = TMR2RL;
             TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
            while(!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
            TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;
            while(k<8)
            {
        if(((valid_data[j])&(1<<q))!=0)  //sending bitwise bit data
        {
           //putchar('1');
            P0_B7=1;
            TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
            while (!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
            TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;//TMR2CN_TR2 = 0;
            k++;q++;
        }
        else
                {// putchar('0');
                                P0_B7=0;TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
                                while (!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
                                TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;//TMR2CN_TR2 = 0;
                                k++;q++;
                                    }
                }

            if(parity!=0)
             {
                //putchar('1');
                P0_B7=1;
                    TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
                    while (!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
                                        TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;//TMR2CN_TR2 = 0;
                                // s
                    }
                else
                {
                    //putchar('0');
                    P0_B7=0;
                    TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
                    while (!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
                    TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;
                }

                                               P0_B7=1;
                                                TMR2RL  = -(4550*3);                  // Init reload values
                                                TMR2    = TMR2RL;                   // Init Timer2 with reload value
                                                 TMR2CN_TR2 = 1;
                                                 while (!TMR2CN_TF2H);                   // Wait for overflow
                                                TMR2CN_TF2H = 0;
                                                    j++;q=0;k=0;


        }
        puts("data");
        TCON_IE0=0;
                P0MDIN  |= (1<<7);
                P0_B2=1;
        // Configure P0.0 as analog input.
      //  puts("data");
                IE_EX0=1;
}
```

Comment: First guess would be, that the card understands only T=0 and you are sending T=1 or vice versa. If you received the ATR successfully, you could interpret it using information from ISO 7816-3, to determine, whether this is the case.

Comment: thanks for comments. now i have been able to communicate with my card.

Comment: i am being able to communicate with smart card but response from the card is fixed to 6e 00 or 6d or 00. please help

Comment: This sounds, as if the card is still transport protected (against theft of unused cards). Contact the supplier to find out out, which procure you have to follow, to make the card understand the full instruction set (e. g. sending a command involving a secret key) ; this may require a signed non-disclosure agreement between you/your company and the supplier. Another possibility is, that you try ISO-commands, but your card is a memory  card or Javacard with a completely different instruction set. Tell mroe about the card and the commands you  send.

Comment: i am using SCOSTA cards. i have got a list o fcommands regarding this card. i have tried all of them. in some commands like CReasting MF i get no response from the card and in others like 00 84 00 00 0e  I get CD 00. Moreover i Have tested the 00 84 00 00 0e on credit cards it works fine giving me some random data with 90 00 as status bytes. i have also tried 00 a4 00 00 02 43 00 command . it returns A4 status. and it is only one byte status. I have verified the status on the CRO.

Comment: Scosta is a specification, not an OS documentation. Therefore it has gaps (e.g. how to arrive at a working card/create the MF). Ask the supplier of your cards for additional information. But it seems, you have no general smart card communication problem, but simply lack information concerning your SCOSTA card.

Comment: ok i will check and reply accordingly.. thanks